# PyQt: How do I handle QPixmaps from a QThread?

Tags: pyqt4, qthread, qpixmap

This has to be the biggest nuisance I've encountered with PyQT: I've hacked together a thumbnailing thread for my application (I have to thumbnail tons of big images), and it looks like it would work (and it *almost* does). My main problem is this error message whenever I send a `SIGNAL` from my thread:

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

I can't figure out how to get around this. I've tried passing a `QIcon` through my `SIGNAL`, but that still generates the same error. If it helps, here's the code blocks which deal with this stuff:

The `Thumbnailer` class:

```
class Thumbnailer(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self, ListWidget, parent = None):
    super(Thumbnailer, self).__init__(parent)
    self.stopped = False
    self.completed = False
    self.widget = ListWidget

  def initialize(self, queue):
    self.stopped = False
    self.completed = False
    self.queue = queue

  def stop(self):
    self.stopped = True

  def run(self):
    self.process()
    self.stop()

  def process(self):
    for i in range(self.widget.count()):
      item = self.widget.item(i)

      icon = QtGui.QIcon(str(item.text()))
      pixmap = icon.pixmap(72, 72)
      icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
      item.setIcon(icon)
```

The part which calls the thread (it occurs when a set of images is dropped onto the list box):

```
  self.thread.images.append(f)

  item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(f, self.ui.pageList)
  item.setStatusTip(f)

  self.thread.start()
```

I'm not sure how to handle this kind of stuff, as I'm just a GUI newbie ;)

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After many attempts, I finally got it. I can't use a `QIcon` or `QPixmap` from within a non-GUI thread, so I had to use a `QImage` instead, as that transmits fine.

Here's the magic code:

**Excerpt from the `thumbnailer.py` `QThread` class:**

```
  icon = QtGui.QImage(image_file)
  self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('makeIcon(int, QImage)'), i, icon)
```

**`makeIcon()` function:**

```
  def makeIcon(self, index, image):
    item = self.ui.pageList.item(index)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(72, 72)
    pixmap.convertFromImage(image) #   <-- This is the magic function!
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
    item.setIcon(icon)
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to make an image thumbnailing thread ;)